# grep in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to write a shell script that allows me to logon to a remote machine to see which users are running vtwm process for more than 14 days. Here is what I have written so far.

There are two problems

1. there might be more than one user with this active process. How do I save all of them in a variable?
2. How do I figure out which one has been logged on for more than 14 days?

The following code was written with the assumption that there is only one user with active vtwm process. But it does not work because grep command does not recognize the variable $u.
so i can never get the date on which the user logged in. I cannot get mth1 and day1 to work because of problems with grep.

```
u=$(ssh host "w | grep vtwm | cut -d' ' -f1")
echo "USER:"$u
if [ -n "$u" ] then           
mth1=$(who | grep -i $u | cut -d' ' -f10 | cut -d'-' -f2)
mth2=$(date +"%m")
day1=$(who | grep -i $u | cut -d' ' -f10 | cut -d"-" -f2)
day2=$(date +"%d")
if [ $mth1==$mth2 ] then
#do something
elif[ $mth1!=$mth2 ] then
#do something
fi
fi
```

Comment: This is confusing code. The variable `$u` is derived by ssh'ing to another machine, but `$mth1` and `$day1` are based on local calls to `who`?

Comment: turn on the shell deubgging feature with `set -vx`. It will be much easier you to see where and why your code starts failing. Sorry to say, is also way too much code for what you're stated goal is. Look at using `awk` as a filter to reduce the # of calls to `who` to 1X. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing all this environment is Linux (you don't have mentioned) , the code below maybe can help you.

- To identify the age of the process, I used `ps -o etime, user, cmd`
- The script receive 2 parameters, limits of days and proc to search
- The ps is showing all process , no matter if have TTY assign or not...
  if you need restrict process with TTY remove the `x` => `ps a -o ...`
- adjust the ssh command to your environment.

Example how call this script: `bash ./mytest.sh 5 bash` , will show **bash** sessions with **+5 days**.

```
# mytest.sh
#--debug-only--# set -xv

[ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "please inform : <#of_days> <regexp>" && exit 1
# receive the # of days
vLimit=$1
# name of proc to search
vProc=$2

vTmp1=/tmp/tmp.myscript.$$

# With this trap , the temp file will be erased at any situation, when
# the script finish sucessufully or interrupted (kill, ctrl-c, ...)
trap "rm $vTmp1 2>/dev/null ; exit" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

# ps manpage :
# etime       ELAPSED   elapsed time since the process was started, in the form [[DD-]hh:]mm:ss.

ssh cinacio@jdivm04 "ps ax -o etime,user,command | grep -i '$vProc' "  >$vTmp1
while read etime user cmd
do

  # if not found the dash "-" on etime, ignore the process, start today...
  ! echo "$etime" | grep -q -- "-" && continue
  vDays=$(echo "$etime" | cut -f1 -d-)
  [ -z "$vDays" ]  && continue
  if [ $vDays -ge $vLimit ]; then
    echo "The user $user still running the proc $cmd on the last $vDays days...."
  fi
done < $vTmp1

#--debug-only--# cat $vTmp1
```

Comment: very nice. But why not pipe ssh into `while read ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter, yes he can use `ssh ... | while read` which will avoid the $vTmp1 treatment. The way I wrote, in my opinion is easy to understand how works, customize the code and then remove what don't needed. Erase always is easy..